# How to interface between QT with Python by Python C api

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am writing a Qt program that is interfacing with python . I have to send the C++ object of Circle class directly  to Python

```
    1) Need to create a Python Module ( let say Shape )
    2) Need to add a Python Class PCircle in Shape module which is equivalent to C++ 
       Circle class.
    3) Do the calculation on Python Environment ( Python 3.4)
    4) Populate the data into PCircle Object in Python
    5) Send it back to Qt Environment by storing the PCircle values to C++ Circle Object    
    and show the changes in real time in display
```

That's how i would describe my problem and what i'm aiming to do, if something is not clear please comment.

Thanks

Comment: there is already pyqt ...

Comment: can u give one example ?

Comment: if I want to access those Python Object from the Command line ? How can we do that ?

Comment: `python -c "from PyQt4 import QtGui;a=QtGui.QApplication();w= QtGui.QWidget();w.setWindowTitle("TEST");w.show();app.exec_();"`  although Im not sure thats what you meant

Comment: You will need to create python bindings for your C++ class using a tool such as [SIP](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/) or [Cython](http://cython.org/) (or see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages) for many other possibilities). If that's too much bother, you could always serialize your `PCircle` class using something like [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) and send it to your C++ program via a socket or something.

Answer (score 0):

1. a module is just a python file ... so just create a file called Shape.py
2. open Shape.py and add

code

```
from PyQt4 import QWidget
class PCircle(QWidget):
    #implement methods here that are available to the QTCircleWidget
```

3. do some calculation of some sort in python land

code

```
def calculation(something):
    return somthing**2
```

4. just add code `my_circle = PCircle(x,y,radius)`
5. print out whatever data you want to give back to the calling program.  the calling program will need to parse that data and do something with it ....

Comment: Let’s say we have Qt Program and a Python Console is embedded into it.
We want to control the top Qt Widgets from the Python Console which is embedded at the bottom.
What should we need to do for the following operations ?
1) How to count  the number of widgets(checkboxes) into  the Qt Widgets group box, their  names & states of checkboxes from python console?
2) How to change the state of each checkboxes from python console?
3) How to add or delete checkboxes from the console ?    please take a look  [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TTBJJE6aEbT3NIRzAyVG4xYzg/edit?usp=sharing